# django can't load images if I add "/" at the urls.py

Tags: django

`url(r'^detail', detail, name="detail"),`  this loads the image,

`url(r'^detail/', detail, name="detail"),` this doesn't loads the image

Somebody tell me why?  thank you

Comment: Can you give some more detail, like where are you loading the Image in template ?

Comment: url(r'^detail/$', detail, name="detail") try this.

Comment: I just want to add an avatar to a blog comment。I mean, why adding this      " / "doesn't refresh the avatar?
{% for comment in comment_list %}
                    <div class="comment">
                        <div class="avatar">
                            <img src="{{ comment.avatar }}" alt="" />
                        </div>{% end for %}

Comment: fix this: {% endfor %}

Comment: sorry，That's my spelling mistake！！！but my question isn't it...  i can loading this picture  without " / "  , once i add the "/" , it  can't

Comment: i  can loading the picture.  but i just  want to  know why this happen...

Comment: can you show the output of `{{ comment.avatar }}`